# Trigger an event on keydown using a specific key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the keydown method to trigger an event in a webpage, for this specific example I need it to be triggered by the X key. I have searched for a little bit now and am getting confused on how to get it to recognize the X key is being pressed. I'm looking for the key code of 88. Here was my code any advice?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ryu').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.ryu-still').hide();
        $('.ryu-ready').show();
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $('.ryu-ready').hide();
        $('.ryu-still').show();
    })
    .mousedown(function() {
        console.log('mousedown');
        // play hadouken sound
        playHadouken();
        //show hadouken and animate it to the right of the screen
        $('.ryu-ready').hide();
        $('.ryu-throwing').show();
        $('.hadouken').finish().show().animate(
            {'left': '1020px'},
            500,
            function() {
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).css('left', '625px');
            }
        );
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
        console.log('mouseup');
        //ryu goes back to his ready position
        $('.ryu-throwing').hide();
        $('.ryu-ready').show();
    })
    .keydown(function() {
        if (keyCode = 88) {
            $('.ryu-ready').hide();
            $('.ryu-cool').show();
        }   
    })
    .keyup(function() {
        if (keyCode = 88) {
            $('.ryu-cool').hide();
            $('.ryu-still').show();
        }
    })


function playHadouken () {
    $('#hadouken-sound')[0].volume = 0.5;
    $('#hadouken-sound')[0].load();
    $('#hadouken-sound')[0].play();
}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in the event parameter:

```
.keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.which === 88) {
        $('.ryu-cool').hide();
        $('.ryu-still').show();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/k5es6na0/

```
<input type = "text" id="inputBox"/>    

    $("#inputBox").on("keydown", function(e){
       var code = e.keyCode;
        if(code == 88){
         alert("X Pressed");   
        }}) ;
```